# EXECUTE sp_executesql not working in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sp-executesql

I'm trying to implement a mechanism that would perform calculations based on dynamically defined algorithms. The way I do it is:

1. Build a string containing the definition of all the variables along with their values,
2. Fetch (from a table) the calculation formula,
3. Invoke `sp_executesql`.

Here is the contents of the string passed as the calculation (contents of variable `@_l_Execute_Formula`):

```
DECLARE @_1 FLOAT = 678;
DECLARE @_2 FLOAT = NULL;
DECLARE @_3 FLOAT = NULL;
SET @_l_Result = @_1 + @_2 + @_3
```

and the invocation is:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql   @_l_Execute_Formula            , 
                      N'@_l_Result FLOAT OUTPUT'       , 
                        @_l_Result = @_l_Result OUTPUT   ;
```

I receive no error message but `@_l_Result` is `NULL`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would expect the value to be *`NULL`*. `[Some value] + NULL = NULL`. Be it a `float` (don't use `float`, it's an awful data type), a `varchar`, or anything else. *`NULL`* is an unknown value; adding it to any other known values causes the resulting value to be unknown as well (thus *`NULL`*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of float values with `NULL` return `NULL`. You might want to escape `NULL` values.

```
DECLARE @_l_Execute_Formula NVARCHAR(MAX) = '

DECLARE @_1 FLOAT = 678;
DECLARE @_2 FLOAT = NULL;
DECLARE @_3 FLOAT = NULL;
SET @_l_Result = ISNULL(@_1, 0) + ISNULL(@_2, 0) + ISNULL(@_3, 0)'

DECLARE @_l_Result FLOAT

EXECUTE sp_executesql   @_l_Execute_Formula            , 
                      N'@_l_Result FLOAT OUTPUT'       , 
                        @_l_Result = @_l_Result OUTPUT;


SELECT @_l_Result  -- Result 678
```